# jQuery click event parent id value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to return the parent div id for a clicked button.  This div will have a class of `.jsgrid`.

Below is my attempt but `rootParentId` returns `undefined`.

I think I've missed something.  Can someone assist?

```js
$("#myButton")
   .on("click", function(e) {
     //let rootParent = $(e.target).parent('.jsGrid');//DOES NOT WORK
     let rootParent = $(e.target).closest('.jsGrid');//CORRECTION
     //console.log('rootParent', rootParent);
     let rootParentId = rootParent.attr('id');
     console.log('rootParentId', rootParentId);
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='#jsGrid1' class='jsGrid'>
  <div>
    <!-- many divs between #jsGrid1 and button clicked -->
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><button id='myButton'>click me</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:  `.parent` to `.closest` and ID is returned.  @Taplar

Comment: The `.jsGrid` is not the parent of the button.  It is an indirect parent.  Use `closest('.jsGrid')` with the correct capitalization

Comment: @Taplar Thank you!  It works perfectly.  Cheers!

Comment: `$(e.target).parentsUntil(".jsGrid")`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Per @Taplar comment - changed `.parent` to `.closest` and ID is returned.